# Da erro caso o nome do projeto não seja "secsu"

Tags: java, lwjgl

Olá, hoje criei um projeto para testar com o nome "secsu" e ele funciona perfeitamente, porem quando tento mudar o nome(*Refactor > Rename*) ele simplesmente da erro.

**Código:**

```
package secsu;

import org.lwjgl.Version;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class Main
{
// We need to strongly reference callback instances.
private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
private GLFWKeyCallback   keyCallback;

// The window handle
private long window;

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

    try {
        init();
        loop();

        // Release window and window callbacks
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        keyCallback.release();
    } finally {
        // Terminate GLFW and release the GLFWErrorCallback
        glfwTerminate();
        errorCallback.release();
    }
}

private void init() {
    // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
    // will print the error message in System.err.
    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err));

    // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
    if ( glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE )
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

    // Configure our window
    glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

    int WIDTH = 300;
    int HEIGHT = 300;

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
    if ( window == NULL )
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

    // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE); // We will detect this in our rendering loop
        }
    });

    // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    // Center our window
    glfwSetWindowPos(
        window,
        (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,
        (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2
    );

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    glfwShowWindow(window);
}

private void loop() {
    // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
    // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
    // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
    // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
    // bindings available for use.
    GL.createCapabilities();

    // Set the clear color
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
    // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
    while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GLFW_FALSE ) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

        // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
        // invoked during this call.
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().run();
}

}
```

**Erro:**

```
Hello LWJGL 3.0.0b SNAPSHOT!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not         initialize class org.lwjgl.system.Library
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess.<clinit>(MemoryAccess.java:22)
at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:594)
at secsu.Main.run(Main.java:34)
at secsu.Main.main(Main.java:113)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: quando fazes o refactor, esta linha `package secsu;` (a primeira) também muda? tens outros arquivos neste pacote?

Comment: @psantos A package não muda e sim, tem os arquivos desse site https://www.lwjgl.org/download

Comment: então tens que mudar também o nome da package para refletir o novo nome. E verificar também se os outros arquivos estão a usar o package antigo

Comment: @psantos Resolvi o problema, o native estava importado errado mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda.